# Multiple providers in a single vagrant file?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I've got a vagrant file that builds a local VM. I want to add the EC2 provider and have the option of either provisioning a local VM or one on EC2.

Can I create configs for multiple providers in the same Vagrantfile and somehow choose which to run when I do `vagrant up`?

Comment: It should be noted that the term "provisioner" is wrong in this context. It should be called "provider" - but I don't want to get into an edit war here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [multi-vm](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/index.html) environment, where every VM can be provisioned with a different provider and you can choose on commandline which one you want to `vagrant up <machine>`.

Comment: For future readers: I've edited the question to call them "providers" rather than "provisioners".

Comment: Just note you cannot have multiple providers running at the same time. In that case you must use multi machine environment.

Answer (score 7):

add box for each provider

```
> vagrant box add precise64 http://file.vagrantup.com/precise64.box
> vagrant box add precise64 http://file.vagrantup.com/precise64_vmware_fusion.box
```

and your Vagrantfile should look like

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box="precise64"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end

  config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
    v.vmx["memsize"] = "2048"
  end
end
```

then create on each provider using following commands

```
> vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
> vagrant up --provider=vmware_fusion
```

Answer (score 2):

You can choose which provider you want to run by `--provider` parameter.

Here is ruby code in `Vagrantfile` which can run different VM depending which provider you have chosen:

```
require 'getoptlong'

# Parse CLI arguments.
opts = GetoptLong.new(
  [ '--provider',     GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ],
)

provider='virtualbox'
begin
  opts.each do |opt, arg|
    case opt
      when '--provider'
        provider=arg
    end # case
  end # each
  rescue
end

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.hostname = "vagrant"
  config.vm.define "default-#{provider}"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vbox, override|
    vbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natdnshostresolver1', 'on']
    vbox.name = "test.local"
    override.vm.box = "ubuntu/wily64"
    override.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.22.22"
  end

  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.ami = "ami-7747d01e"
    aws.instance_type = "m3.medium"
    override.vm.box = "dummy"
    override.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box"
    override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
  end

end
```

So by the default provider is virtualbox, but you can specify from the command line, like:

```
vagrant up --provider=aws
```

Answer (score 1):

To run VM locally you can run:
    `vagrant up --provider=virtualbox`
and if you'd like to run VM using different provider then you can use:
    `vagrant up --provider=aws`

However, remember that you have to install appropriate provider plugin before you will use it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [gist posted by @tknerr](https://gist.github.com/tknerr/5753319) which works with all providers such as virtualbox, AWS and managed in combination with the vagrant-omnibus plugin. Here is the code from `Vagrantfile`:

```
#
# Vagrantfile for testing
#
Vagrant::configure("2") do |config|

  # the Chef version to use
  config.omnibus.chef_version = "11.4.4"

  def configure_vbox_provider(config, name, ip, memory = 384)
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vbox, override| 
      # override box url
      override.vm.box = "opscode_ubuntu-13.04_provisionerless"
      override.vm.box_url = "https://opscode-vm.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/opscode_ubuntu-13.04_provisionerless.box"
      # configure host-only network
      override.vm.hostname = "#{name}.local"
      override.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip
      # enable cachier for local vbox vms
      override.cache.auto_detect = true

      # virtualbox specific configuration
      vbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, 
        "--memory", memory,
        "--name", name
      ] 
    end
  end

  def configure_aws_provider(config)
    config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
      # use dummy box
      override.vm.box = "aws_dummy_box"
      override.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box"
      # override ssh user and private key
      override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
      override.ssh.private_key_path = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/mccloud_rsa"

      # aws specific settings
      aws.access_key_id = "XXXX"
      aws.secret_access_key = "XXXXX"
      aws.ami = "ami-524e4726"
      aws.region = "eu-west-1"
      aws.availability_zone = "eu-west-1c"
      aws.instance_type = "m1.small"
      aws.security_groups = [ "mccloud", "http" ]
      aws.keypair_name = "mccloud-key-tlc"
    end
  end

  def configure_managed_provider(config, server)
    config.vm.provider :managed do |managed, override|
      # use dummy box
      override.vm.box = "managed_dummy_box"
      override.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/tknerr/vagrant-managed-servers/raw/master/dummy.box"

      # link with this server
      managed.server = server
    end
  end

#
# define a separate VMs for the 3 providers (vbox, aws, managed) 
# because with Vagrant 1.2.2 you can run a VM with only one provider at once
#
[:aws, :vbox, :esx].each do |provider|
  #
  # Sample VM per provider
  #
  config.vm.define :"sample-app-#{provider}" do | sample_app_config |

    case provider
    when :vbox
      configure_vbox_provider(sample_app_config, "sample-app", "33.33.40.10")
    when :aws
      configure_aws_provider(sample_app_config)
    when :esx    
      configure_managed_provider(sample_app_config, "33.33.77.10")  
    end

    sample_app_config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
      chef.cookbooks_path = [ './cookbooks/sample-app-0.1.0' ]
      chef.add_recipe "sample-app"
      chef.json = {
        :sample_app => {
          :words_of_wisdom => "Vagrant on #{provider} Rocks!"
        }
      }
    end
  end
end

end
```

Answer (score -1):

From [the Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html):

> Multiple config.vm.provision methods can be used to define multiple provisioners. These provisioners will be run in the order they're defined.

eg.:
First install puppet in the machine and then run some puppet manifests:

```
    $script = "
    wget http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
    sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo aptitude -yy install puppet
    "


    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script

    config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
       puppet.manifests_path = "manifest/puppet"
       puppet.manifest_file = "init.pp"
    end

    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Second shell provisioner"
```

Comment: the question was about multiple 'providers' not 'provisioners'

Comment: The question was originally asked about provisioners and then edited to ask about providers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can specify multiple machines by using the `config.vm.define` method call, for example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Hello"

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "apache"
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "mysql"
  end
end
```

See: [Defining multiple machines at Vagranup Docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/index.html) and [Providers](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/)